# How to get right-angled lines with "Connect to Columns" relationships?

Tags: mysql-workbench

All the other relationship notations draw relationship lines with right angles, but in the "Connect to Columns" notation, it is always a straight line from column to column.

Can I have curved or right-angled lines (as opposite to straight lines) in MySQL Workbench, while having "Connect to Columns" relationship notation?

Comment: Version of MySQL Workbench is 6.1.7.